# An easy way to separate my desktop PC from my wireless devices?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, security, switch

At the moment I have an ISP-provided wireless router and my PC is connected to it via an ethernet cable.

For security reasons, I'd like to separate my PC from my (and my guests') wireless devices. Unfortunately, my router has no "guest network" feature.

As far as I understand, there are at least two ways to make sure my PC won't be reachable from the wireless devices:

1. Get a new router (with the "guest network" feature).
2. Get a managed switch (to create a VLAN).

But since my PC doesn't have to talk to any other device, I thought maybe there is an easier way?

Comment: There is just disable File Sharing and configure Windows to NOT discover devices on the network.  This will essentially isolate your machine from other device, they can ping your device and/or listen to any applicable service, but you could also just modify your host file on the other devices to blackhole your device (i.e. hostname 127.0.0.1)

Comment: Enable built-in firewall/brandmauer and set 2 rules at the top of the rules list - 1st allows the traffic (all protocols) from router's subnet default gateway (router's address) and subnet's broadcast, 2nd drops the traffic from any address within this subnet. With these 2 rules all traffic from any node except the router will be dropped.

Comment: Let alone whether an router (especially when it's ISP-provided) has customizable firewall. L3 firewall (e.g. iptables) does not deal with traffics traverse within the switch part of it / the broadcast domain. (Yes it could drop "subnet traffics" that you route to the router by avoiding prefix route or so and forcing it to "loopback-forward", but that will break things in the wired LAN as well and every wired hosts will need to be configured that way.)

Comment: But with *wrt or so router that is equipped ebtables / nftables (bridge family table), you might be able to achieve what you want because the wireless AP and the LAN NIC (that is connected to the switch part of it) of the router are likely bridged, in which case you can prevent traffics from the AP from going out of the LAN NIC (and the other way round). (Or if possible, you can even just "un-bridge" the LAN NIC and the wireless AP and filter at L3.)